# SQL Server: How can I group multiple row values into separate columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to create a `SELECT` query that will allow me to combine multiple phone numbers for a Contact into separate columns.

For example, I would like the following

```
Email  |  Phone  |  ID  |
------------------------|
x@x.com| 555-5555| 001  |
x@x.com| 555-5556| 001  |
```

to instead be:

```
Email  |  Phone  |  Phone2  | Phone3 |  ID  |
--------------------------------------------|
x@x.com| 555-5555| 555-5556 |  NULL  | 001  |
```

Although this may be bad practice, it is strictly so I can export the results to a CSV in order to upload that data into a CRM system which does not allow any duplicates when importing. I have looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer that deals with phone numbers since `MIN` and `MAX` will only allow for two and no more.

The most complicated part is how the database is structured and will most likely involve a complicated query. Here's what I tried so far but can only get 2 numbers and I need the remaining columns (please keep in mind, I'm not a SQL guy):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       C.CONTACTID,
       MAX(T.NUMBERVALUE) AS Phone1,
       MIN(T.numbervalue) AS Phone2
FROM TBL_PHONE T
     JOIN TBL_CONTACT C ON C.CONTACTID = T.CONTACTID
     JOIN TBL_EMAIL E ON E.CONTACTID = C.CONTACTID
WHERE T.NUMBERVALUE IS NOT NULL
      AND LEN(T.NUMBERVALUE) > 0
GROUP BY C.CONTACTID;
```

Comment: Pivot or Dynamic pivot depending on how many phon numbers you expect there to be?

Comment: Can see similar use here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715004/create-columns-from-rows-in-sql-server

Comment: Wow you guys are fast! I expect there to only be a total of 3 phone numbers. I'll look into it. Thanks a lot for how fast you were!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a dynamic pivot way:

```
declare @table table (Email varchar(64), Phone varchar(16), ID varchar(3))
insert into @table
values

('x@x.com','555-5555','001'),
('x@x.com','555-5556','001'),
('x@x.com','555-5557','001'),
('x@x.com','555-5558','001'),
('x@xdd.com','333-5556','002'),
('x@xdd.com','444-5556','002'),
('x@xdd.com','777-5556','002')


select
    Email
    ,Phone
    ,ID
    ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by Phone) as RN
into #staging
from 
    @table




DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(RN)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RN FROM #staging) AS RN

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Email, ID, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #staging
    PIVOT(MAX(Phone) 
          FOR RN IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery

drop table #staging
```

**If you are only expecting 3, as you stated, you can skip the dynamic...**

```
declare @table table (Email varchar(64), Phone varchar(16), ID varchar(3))
insert into @table
values

('x@x.com','555-5555','001'),
('x@x.com','555-5556','001'),
('x@xdd.com','333-5556','002'),
('x@xdd.com','444-5556','002'),
('x@xdd.com','777-5556','002')

;with cte as(
select
    Email
    ,Phone
    ,ID
    ,row_number() over (partition by ID order by Phone) as RN
from 
    @table)

select
    Email
    ,max(case when RN = 1 then Phone end) as Phone1
    ,max(case when RN = 2 then Phone end) as Phone2
    ,max(case when RN = 3 then Phone end) as Phone3
    ,ID
from
    cte
group by
    Email
    ,ID
```

Comment: I'm completely blown away how fast you came up with that! Just gave it a shot and I think its just what I need. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries. I added a simple solution as well.

Comment: I am able to use this solution with joins right? I've added them now using your code as a template and am confused what 'cte' is. I am getting a OutOfMemoryException.. The only difference is without the declaration of @table and am using the columns i already have.

Comment: @ZacHerman CTE is `common table expression`. You can use joins with it (inside and outside the cte). I'm not sure why you'd get `OutOfMemoryException` but feel free to post your code in your original question and i'll take a look this time

Comment: ^ never mind.. something must have been going on with SSMS because i restarted and its working. Thank you!

Comment: Im still having some issues.. where do i post the code?

Comment: @ZacHerman I would open another (new) question. It's what the StackOverflow Help center states should be done. I'm sure myself, or someone else will answer quickly. It's good to link this question to the new one you open though.

Comment: Wow.. There were no emails for a company so thats what was messing it up. Sorry to waste your time. Thanks.

Comment: HAAH, no worries mate!