# Eliminating Duplicates with SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

A few months ago I asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422797/sql-server-how-can-i-group-multiple-row-values-into-separate-columns). I am now experiencing issues in that, my client is telling me they are missing data. I went back through the query below and found that when removing the `P.NUMBERVALUE` or essentially removing the phone number entirely, the missing data appears. However, removing the phone number from the query completely defeats the purpose of using this CTE. The only thing I can think of is that if a record has no phone number at all, its not selected.

My questions is, how do I go about getting ALL of the records and avoid duplicate rows as much as possible. The results of this query will become a CSV that I have to use to import the records into a CRM and there cannot be duplicates. As always, any help provided is greatly appreciated.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        C.COMPANYID AS 'Account CRM ID',
        C.NAME AS 'Company Name',
        --  P.NUMBERVALUE AS Phone,
        A.LINE1 AS 'Street',
        A.LINE2 AS 'Suite # / Unit # / Other',
        A.CITY AS 'City',
        A.STATE AS 'State',
        A.POSTALCODE AS 'Zipcode',
        C.CUST_County_111923725 AS 'County',
        C.CATEGORY AS 'Lead Category',
        C.NUMEMPLOYEES AS 'Number of Employees',
        C.INDUSTRY AS 'Industry Type',
        C.REVENUE AS 'Revenue',
        C.CUST_FrequencyofService_111240157 AS 'Schedule Frequency',
        C.WEBADDRESS AS 'Website',
        C.CUST_GeneraleMail_112218273 AS 'General Email',
        C.CUST_TypeofService_110014852 AS 'Service Type',
        C.CUST_CurrentMethod_111527894 AS 'Current Method',
        C.CREATEDATE AS 'Create Date',
        C.CUST_Comments_111653133 AS 'Company Comments'
        --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.COMPANYID ORDER BY P.NUMBERVALUE) AS RN
    FROM 
        TBL_COMPANY C
    --JOIN TBL_PHONE P ON P.COMPANYID = C.COMPANYID
    JOIN 
        TBL_ADDRESS A ON A.COMPANYID = C.COMPANYID
)
SELECT 
    [Account CRM ID],
    [Company Name],
    -- Email,
    --MAX(CASE
    --        WHEN RN = 1
    --        THEN Phone
    --    END) AS Phone1,
    --MAX(CASE
    --        WHEN RN = 2
    --        THEN Phone
    --    END) AS Phone2,
    --MAX(CASE
    --        WHEN RN = 3
    --        THEN Phone
    --    END) AS Phone3,
    Street,
    [Suite # / Unit # / Other],
    City,
    State,
    Zipcode,
    County,
    [Lead Category],
    [Number of Employees],
    [Industry Type],
    [Revenue],
    [Schedule Frequency],
    Website,
    [General Email],
    [Service Type],
    [Current Method],
    [Create Date],
    [Company Comments]
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    DATALENGTH(Street) > 0
GROUP BY 
    [Account CRM ID], [Company Name],
    --  Email,
    Street, [Suite # / Unit # / Other],
    City, State, Zipcode, County,
    [Lead Category],
    [Number of Employees],
    [Industry Type], [Revenue],
    [Schedule Frequency],
    Website,
    [General Email], [Service Type],
    [Current Method], [Create Date],
    [Company Comments]
ORDER BY 
    [Company Name];
```

Comment: Probably as simple as changing the INNER JOIN to TBL_PHONE to be a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what group by does... If you group by ALL fields in the query, this does the same as the DISTINCT you have in the CTE

Comment: Perhaps you are correct @Milney, SQL is not my strong suit however, the query would not execute without the group by clause which is why I added it. Please educate me on best practices. That's why I'm here.

Comment: @SeanLange - You my friend... That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Can someone explain why this was down voted? I'm here to improve, not wonder what I did wrong with no explanation.. If I'm doing something incorrectly, tell me!