# What is the SQL code for aggregating values?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
GR    WORD NO.
1      A    4
2      B    5
3      C    6
1      G    5
2      H    5
3      I    5
```

I would like to get the following table:

```
GR     4    5    6
1      1    1    0
2      0    2    0
3      0    1    1
```

For each `GR` column value I count the `NO.` values.

Comment: oracle <> sql-server

Comment: @Avi . . .  I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a dynamic solution:

```
--Sample data
--CREATE TABLE tbl (GR int, WORD char(1), [NO] int)
--INSERT INTO tbl values 
--(1,'A',4),
--(2,'B',5),
--(3,'C',6),
--(1,'G',5),
--(2,'H',5),
--(3,'I',5)

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = '
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
PIVOT(
COUNT(WORD) FOR [NO] IN (' + 
    (SELECT STUFF(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST([NO] AS VARCHAR(10))) 
            FROM tbl 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
     , 1, 1, ''))
    + ')
) p
'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a conditional aggregation

```
select 
   GR
   ,[4] = count(case when NO. = 4 then WORD end)
   ,[5] = count(case when NO. = 5 then WORD end)
   ,[6] = count(case when NO. = 6 then WORD end)
from YourTable
group by GR
```

Or a pivot

```
select * 
from YourTable
pivot(
count(WORD) for NO. in ([4],[5],[6])
) p
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to do it automatically without hard coding the values of GR. Since there can be many values for GR.

Comment: Then you need a dynamic pivot. Google that, but here is a good resource: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: Here is another answer i did on that https://stackoverflow.com/a/45423065/6167855