# How can I dynamically convert row to columns and have different column name for each column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

How can I convert rows into columns and create different name for each column?

```
create table #TempTable  (InvoiceNum int,State varchar(2), ChargeName varchar(50),  PercentageRate decimal(5,3), FlatRate decimal(5,2))
insert into #TempTable values   (235736, 'AZ','Inspection & Policy Fee',  NULL,250.00)
                                ,(235736, 'AZ','Surplus Line Tax',0.03,NULL)
                                ,(235736, 'AZ','Stamping Fee',0.002,NULL
```

)

I need something like that:

[image]

UPDATE:

Using example I was able to unpivot it but the result is not what I wanted to:

```
create table #TempTable  (InvoiceNum int,State varchar(2), ChargeName varchar(50),  PercentageRate decimal(5,3), FlatRate decimal(5,2))
insert into #TempTable values   (235736, 'AZ','Inspection & Policy Fee',  NULL,250.00)
                                ,(235736, 'AZ','Surplus Line Tax',0.03,NULL)
                                ,(235736, 'AZ','Stamping Fee',0.002,NULL)

--select * from @TempTable


Declare @SQL nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)

select @SQL = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ChargeName) 
                    from #TempTable
                    group by ChargeName, InvoiceNum
                    order by InvoiceNum
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
--select @SQL
set   @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @SQL + '  from
        (
            select PercentageRate, ChargeName
            from #TempTable
        ) x
        pivot
        (
        max(PercentageRate)
        for ChargeName in (' + @SQL + ')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Running below query gives me this:

[image]

Why ChargeName is not on the first row? I would expect to see it like this: What am I missing?

[image]

```
declare  @TempTable table  (InvoiceNum int,StateID varchar(2), ChargeName varchar(50),  PercentageRate decimal(5,3), FlatRate decimal(5,2))
insert into @TempTable values   (235736, 'AZ','Inspection & Policy Fee',  NULL,250.00)
                                ,(235736, 'AZ','Surplus Line Tax',0.03,NULL)
                                ,(235736, 'AZ','Stamping Fee',0.002,NULL)
select 
        InvoiceNum,
        ChargeName,
        StateID,
        PercentageRate,
        FlatRate,
        row_number() over (partition by InvoiceNum order by ChargeName) as RN
into #TempTable
 from @TempTable #TempTable

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(RN)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RN FROM #TempTable) AS RN

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT InvoiceNum,  ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #TempTable
    PIVOT(MAX(ChargeName) 
          FOR RN IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
drop table #TempTable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: If you still think this is not a duplicate, try to add a calculated column for Tax1, Tax2.. using row_number and then use above link to achieve the results you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I used that example to get to some point. But got confused how to modify it in order to get desirable result. I updated question. Thanks again

Comment: This is going to require multiple pivots and get real ugly. I show how to do dynamic columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45423065/6167855) but it's going to require you to do it 3 times i think

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: @scsimon Thank you . I used your example but for some reason I get ChargeName in each row. What am I doing wrong?  I updated with picture.

Comment: I’ll hammer this out if you still need it?

Comment: That would be awesome.I really need it. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I would just join the temp table multiple times as needed.
Given your #TempTable

```
SELECT T1.InvoiceNum,
    Tax1_Jurisdiction = T1.State, Tax1_TaxType = T1.ChargeName, Tax1_Percent = T1.PercentageRate, Tax1_FixedRate = T1.FlatRate, 
    Tax2_Jurisdiction = T2.State, Tax2_TaxType = T2.ChargeName, Tax2_Percent = T2.PercentageRate, Tax2_FixedRate = T2.FlatRate, 
    Tax3_Jurisdiction = T3.State, Tax3_TaxType = T3.ChargeName, Tax3_Percent = T3.PercentageRate, Tax3_FixedRate = T3.FlatRate
FROM #TempTable T1
JOIN #TempTable T2 ON T1.InvoiceNum = T2.InvoiceNum
JOIN #TempTable T3 ON T1.InvoiceNum = T3.InvoiceNum
WHERE T1.ChargeName = 'Inspection & Policy Fee'
    AND T2.ChargeName = 'Surplus Line Tax'
    AND T3.ChargeName = 'Stamping Fee'
;
```

Comment: Is the number of charges also dynamic? If not then you could use variables or another temp table to specify the different charge codes and the order they should be applied.